# I can't login to my desktop

Tags: xorg, login, xserver

Xubuntu 16.04.

When I login from the login screen, I am simply returned back to the login screen. I logged out last night,left the PC running, tried to login again this morning and could not. I have reboot the PC, the issue remains.

I can login to a terminal (tty1, tty2 etc) no problem.

The only thing I did out of the ordinary yesterday (a few hours before logging out) was switch to tty1 and start another X server running

```
startx -- :10
```

I did this to test the ability to run multiple X servers during a conversation I was having at the time about X servers.

I beleive I have somehow borked my X server, can somebody please advise how best to troubleshoot, or better still how to fix the issue ?

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was fun ! I fixed the issue and thought I would share for any body interested.

The ownership of my `~/.ICEauthority` file was incorrect. That file should be owned by me but it was in fact owned by root.

Turns out that I had ran the `startx` command as root, which changed the  ownership of the file. ( I really didn't think I had, but a quick search through my history revealed the truth).

Apparently it is also possible for root to claim ownership of the `~/.Xauthority` file as well, but in my case it didn't.

To change ownership of the file back to me, I used `chown` (as root).

```
sudo chown myusername.myusername .ICEauthority
```

So, in short don't run `startx` as root. If you do, and end up stuck in a login loop, then check the ownership of `~/.ICEauthority` and `~/.Xauthority`.